# Retrieving the "match of value" in an ADD Diff computed by EMF Compare

Tags: java, eclipse, emf, eclipse-emf, emf-compare

I am fairly new to EMF and have recently started using EMF Compare to compute the differences between two models. For the moment, those differences are simply printed to the console, and I try to retrieve all the useful information from them.

When I print an ADD Diff corresponding for example to the add of an `eAttribute`, it looks like this:

```
UNRESOLVED LEFT ADD org.eclipse.emf.compare.internal.spec.ReferenceChangeSpec{
  reference=EClass.eStructuralFeatures,
  value=EAttribute@7e8dcdaanom,
  parentMatch=org.eclipse.emf.compare.internal.spec.MatchSpec{
    left=EClass@5cdd09b1SystemOfAirport,
    right=EClass@8c11eeeSystemOfAirport,
    origin=<null>,
    #differences=2,
    #submatches=5
  },
  match of value=org.eclipse.emf.compare.internal.spec.MatchSpec{
    left=EAttribute@7e8dcdaanom,
    right=<null>,
    origin=<null>,
    #differences=1,
    #submatches=0
  }
}
```

What I would like to retrieve is the `MatchSpec` corresponding to the *match of value* attribute of my `ReferenceChangeSpec`. However, I can't seem to find the corresponding getter in the `ReferenceChangeSpec` documentation. I have tried looking into the GitHub code for Diffs and especially `Diff.toString()`, but it hasn't brought me any further, that's why I am asking for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking this question on the [EMF Compare forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/164/), I have been able to find the solution to my problem.

The trick is to use `Comparison.getMatch(EObject)`. So for a `Difference d` of kind **ADD** you want to retrieve the **match of value**:
`Match matchOfValue = comparison.getMatch(((ReferenceChangeSpec) difference).getValue());`